# Exclude WP Supersized full screen background slideshow plugin on landingpage?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to exclude the WP Supersized full screen background slideshow plugin on a certain landing page/splash page? Right now the preloader shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue (though for me it was the preloader image diplaying on the Wordpress login page, though it doesn't show on any other admin page as per my settings. The login page is possibly an oversight by the plugin author).

I was unable to target or override using my theme's stylesheet, unfortunately, though adding the following line of code to the plugin stylesheet (I know, I never like updating core files either) did the trick. No more unnecessary pre-loader!

In the plugin stylesheet (wp-supersized/css/supersized.css) add the following line of code (substitute the body class if targeting a different page. You can do this by viewing the source code of your specific page)

```
body.login div#supersized-loader { display:none; }
```

I hope this helps you or anyone else who's run into this issue, and hopefully the plugin author resolves the issue in a future update. I love this plugin!

EDIT: I should note this is for the plugin version 3.1.6 which is the most current version as of this writing.